# XSLT-1.0 | Get first and last node and call specific template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am relatively new to XLST and this might be a typical beginners problem, but I can't figure it out.
Hope you can help and understand me. Thank you in advance. :-)

I try to transform a big XML file to another one, but can't figure out how I can get the first and last node and surround them with other nodes.

The problem is all **fruit**-nodes are created iteratively.

In my opinion, I should add the surrounding **fruits**-nodes after all **fruit** - elements are created.

I already tried something like:

```xml
<xsl:template name="tplFruit" match="PARENT_FRUIT">
   <xsl:apply-template select="(//element[@name='fruit'])[1]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="addFruits">
   <fruits>
</xsl:template>
```

```xml
<xsl:template name="tplFruit" match="PARENT_FRUIT">
   <xsl:apply-template select="(//element[@name='fruit'])[last()]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="addFruits">
   </fruits>
</xsl:template>
```

But it doesn't work and I am pretty sure another error will occur because I open and close the elements **fruits** in different templates.

The following xml is given (Input - XML):

```
<root>
... other elements ...

<PARENT_FRUIT>
   <different_node nr="1" />
   <different_node nr="2" />
   <different_node nr="3" />

   <fruit>
      <name>Apple</name>
      <calorien>999</calorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>      
      <name>cherry</name>
      <calorien>999</calorien>
      <color>red</color></fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>banana</name>
      <calorien>999</calorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>

   <different_node nr="4" />
   <different_node nr="5" />
   <different_node nr="6" />

   <fruit>
      <name>Apple2</name>
      <calorien>999</calorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>cherry2</name>
      <calorien>999</calorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>banana2</name>
      <calorien>999</calorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>

...and so on...
</PARENT_FRUIT>

...other elements ...
</root>
```

The following XML should be my end result:

```xml
<root>
... other elements ...

<PARENT_FRUIT>
... other elements ...

<fruits>
   <fruit>
      <name>apple</name>
      <calorien>999</carlorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>cherry</name>
      <calorien>999</carlorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>banana</name>
      <calorien>999</carlorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>apple2</name>
      <calorien>999</carlorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>cherry2</name>
      <calorien>999</carlorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>
      <name>banana2</name>
      <calorien>999</carlorien>
      <color>red</color>
   </fruit>

... and so on ...
<fruits>

... other elements ...
<PARENT_FRUIT>

... other elements ...
</root>
```

### EDIT 04.06.2019:

I use XLST Version 1.0

Comment: Where you say "The following xml is given", is that your input XML, or your current output? I do note your XSLT has a template matching `PARENT_FRUIT` and also tries to select `element` elements, which suggests your input XML is something different, so it would help if you showed that. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C Updated my original question. 
Unfortunately, I cannot show my original input XML due data protection and it would be way bigger than 5Million lines.

Comment: I fixed your input XML by changing `carlorien` to `calorien`. Now it is _well-formed_.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *first* and *last* from desired result. All I see is all *fruit* nodes enclosed inside a new *fruits* element. Not sure if you need to remove or re-position the sibling *different_node*.

Comment: @Parfait I just want to enclose the fruit elements, the other attributes should be re-postioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with all of the *other elements* grouped at the beginning, the following, simple, XSLT-1.0 stylesheet will do the job. Otherwise it would be unclear where you want to place the `<fruits>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PARENT_FRUIT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::fruit)]|@*"/>
            <fruits>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fruit"/>
            </fruits>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    ... other elements ...

    <PARENT_FRUIT>
        <different_node nr="1"/>
        <different_node nr="2"/>
        <different_node nr="3"/>
        <different_node nr="4"/>
        <different_node nr="5"/>
        <different_node nr="6"/>
        <fruits><fruit>
                <name>Apple</name>
                <calorien>999</calorien>
                <color>red</color>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>      
                <name>cherry</name>
                <calorien>999</calorien>
                <color>red</color>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>
                <name>banana</name>
                <calorien>999</calorien>
                <color>red</color>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>
                <name>Apple2</name>
                <calorien>999</calorien>
                <color>red</color>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>
                <name>cherry2</name>
                <calorien>999</calorien>
                <color>red</color>
            </fruit>
            <fruit>
                <name>banana2</name>
                <calorien>999</calorien>
                <color>red</color>
            </fruit>
        </fruits>
    </PARENT_FRUIT>

    ...other elements ...
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match on `fruit[1]` and wrap all `fruit` elements into a `fruits` container and match on the other `fruit` elements to not process them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fruit[1]">
      <fruits>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../fruit"/>
      </fruits>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fruit[position() > 1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```